# Lua quirk with s:format()

Tags: lua

It seems like this syntax should work but doesn't:

```
> print "%i":format(42)
%i  
[string "return print "%i":format(42)"]:1: attempt to index a nil value
```

This also fails:

```
> print ("%i":format(42))
[string "print ("%i":format(42))"]:1: ')' expected near ':'
```

This sort of works:

```
> print (("%i"):format(42))
42  
=> [string "return print ("%i"):format(42)"]:1: attempt to index a nil value
```

Can somebody explain what's going on and tell me how it's supposed to be done?

(I'm aware of `string.format("%i", 42)` but I'm trying out this other syntax shown in the docs.)

**Edit:** Further testing shows this is partially an issue with repl.it. Running the interpreter locally doesn't show any error for the last example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to `string.format`, it's a general syntax feature of Lua: in method calls on complicated expressions, you need to enclose the expression in parentheses.

See *prefixexp* in the [Lua BNF](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#9):

```
prefixexp ::= var | functioncall | ‘(’ exp ‘)’
functioncall ::=  prefixexp args | prefixexp ‘:’ Name args
```